# How to calculate "customer months" in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, array-formulas

What would be the easiest way to calculate the number of customers months at at any given date?

```
#   start   end
1   01/16   01/17
2   01/16   07/17
3   07/16   01/17
```

Let's say start month is included and end month excluded.

The result I would like is:

```
<= (start of) 01/16: total customer months = 0
e.g. (start of) 03/16 = 4 (2 customers for each 2 months)
e.g. (start of) 08/16 = 15 (2 customers for each 7 months, 1 customer for 1 month)
>= (start of) 07/17 = 36 (12 + 18 + 6)
```

Comment: An [**array formula**](https://support.office.com/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) is the best way to perform a calculation over a dataset.

Comment: That's what I thought hence the tag. I cannot find out how to add the necessary conditions to make this work, though.

Comment: There are numerous tutorials and other resources available online to teach you how to use array formulas

Comment: "Proud to be a member of this rich community of knowledge-sharers!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Put your data into Excel Table, where `Table1` will contain the start and end of membership

   [image]
2. Create the following function to return the elapsed customer membership calculation

   ```
   Private Function get_duration(ByVal checkdate As Range) As Integer

   Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table1")
   Dim duration_check As Integer
   Dim total_duration As Long

   total_duration = 0

       For Each cell In tbl.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
           If (DateDiff("m", cell.Offset(0, 1), checkdate) <= 0) Then
               duration_check = DateDiff("m", cell, checkdate)
               If duration_check < 0 Then
                   duration_check = 0
               End If

               total_duration = total_duration + duration_check
           End If
       Next cell

   get_duration = total_duration

   End Function
   ```
3. Feed the function a specific cell range you want to check. And done! *Technically this is the question answered, but check the part below to see how it could be implemented*

---

4. Implementation in  practice *(real example)*. Create `Table2` that will contain all the dates you want to check (I just included what you described in your question example)

   [image]
5. Create a simple procedure to loop through all the `CheckDate` Values **which invokes our `get_duration()` function**

   ```
   Private Sub loop_through_checkdates()

   Dim tbl2 As ListObject: Set tbl2 = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Table2")

   For Each cell In tbl2.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange
       cell.Offset(0, 1) = get_duration(cell)
   Next cell

   End Sub
   ```
6. Provides result as expected in your question

   [image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Chris.

Comment: Glad it helped, though for future reference, you really should include code of your current efforts. I think that's also why ashlee was hesitant to post any specific solution. I'm sure she meant well.